# How to store word documents content in SQL Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to make a web app using EF Core that give a word documents (test exam questions and answers) from client and store it content to a table in SQL Server.

The table should have two columns, `question` and `answers` (a,b,c,d).

How can I get documents from client and how can I split question and answers to store them?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use the Varchar(max) Column type for Answer Column that is accessible in SQL 2005 and subsequent versions.

This can hold up to 2GB of data and is processed as a regular varchar.
The TEXT type is still available, although it's largely for SQL 2000 and earlier backward compatibility.
Because NVARCHAR uses two bytes per character, the maximum number of characters that may be stored is around one billion. A column of type NVARCHAR(MAX) can hold up to 2GB of data.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, but i don't know how to read the file line by line and how to split answers and questions

Comment: You can read the text file line by line.  

` string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(textFile);       
    foreach (string line in lines)  
    Console.WriteLine(line);  
`
Read the question or answer line you can specify the  Q and A in line than search specific line for Question and Answer.